# Why does the output keep returning a 'None' value at the last?

Tags: python, function, range, output, nonetype

```
def range_test(start, end):
    while start <= end:
        print(start)
        start+=1

print(range_test(1,5))
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `range_test` doesn't have a return value, that's why it results in None

Answer (score 3):

You're saying to print the output of `range_test`, but you aren't returning any value.

To fix this, just remove the print and run `range_test(1, 5)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `None` at the end is the `None` returned by `range_test`.  Change it to:

```
def range_test(start, end):
    while start <= end:
        print(start)
        start+=1

range_test(1,5)  # this function already prints, no need to print its return
```

or if you prefer to have `range_test` return something you can print (rather than doing the printing itself and returning nothing), do:

```
def range_test(start, end):
    to_print = ""
    while start <= end:
        to_print += f"{start}\n"
        start+=1
    return to_print

print(range_test(1,5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't define a `return` value in your code, so by default it returns None. Calling `print(func)` prints the returned value. It would display normally if you did either of these:

```
def range_test(start, end):
    while start <= end:
        print(start)
        start+=1

range_test(1,5)

def range_test(start, end):
    range_list = []
    while start <= end:
        range_list.append(start)
        start+=1
    return "\n".join(range_list)
range_test(1,5)
```